# Как найти пользователей одной роли

Tags: java

Есть сущность USER, в ней есть столбец ROLE, он может быть: ADMIN,TENANT,LANDLORD. Я через Postman делаю запрос на вывод всех TENANT, как мне выбрать из USER именно TENANT?

Верно ли я делаю, что сначала хочу пройтись по всем ролям и найти нужную.
Затем добавить тех, которых отобрал в новый лист.
Потом пройтись по этому листу и вывести того, которого запросил пользователь по ID (здесь нужна помощь).

У меня был такой вариант:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:read')")
    public User landlordGet(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {
        List<User> sort = userRepository.findAll();
        List<User> res = new ArrayList<>();
        for (User us: sort) {
            if (us.getRole().equals(Role.TENANT)){
                res.add(us);
            }
        }
        ...

        return user;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<User> findByRole(@Param("role") String role);
```

или так, что надежнее

```
@Query(value = "select * from user where role = :role ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<User> findByRole(@Param("role") String role);
```

Добавить запрос в репозитарий